# Calling a convert up to the Torah as "Ben Avraham Avinu"

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, torah-reading

I hear sometimes people being called up to the Torah as "Ploni Ben Avraham Avinu"
I assume that these are people who - by their own choice - wish to advertise that they are converts. (I also assume, that most geirim are more circumspect, and prefer to be called up as "Ben Avraham")

Does anyone know more on this?

When being called to the Torah, is a convert required to give his name as “Ben Avraham Avinu”?

Comment: gordon613 @IsraelReader changed your question. Was this your intent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When an adopted child is called to the torah, how are they named?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36869/when-an-adopted-child-is-called-to-the-torah-how-are-they-named)

Comment: @Robev: Not exactly. I know that a convert is not in general required to give his name as "Ben Avraham Avinu". I am interested as to why some do however give their name as "Ben Avraham Avinu" and not "Ben Avraham" and whether this is merely a case of personal preference or whether this is due to some other factor.

Comment: @sabbahillel. I don't think so. I don't think this question discusses the formula of "Ben Avraham Avinu" at all.

Comment: @gordon613 The abswer that I point to explains why some use the adopted father's name and some use *ben Avraham Avinu* or even *ben Avraham*.

Comment: @sabbahillel. I apologize for being obtuse, but I have read your answer several times (in the link that you kindly provided) and I find no mention of "Avinu", neither in the answer itself nor in the comments

Comment: @gordon613 The point is that when someone refers to Ben Avraham, it means Ben Avraham Avinu. It does not mean that he is taking on some other patronymic, unlike the case of someone who takes on his adopted father's name.