# Do you call a yid who's had a giyur LECHUMRA "Ben/Bat Avraham Avinu"?

Tags: names, conversion-to-judaism

Do you call a yid who's had a giyur LECHUMRA "Ben/Bat Avraham Avinu"?

So basically if a yid grows up with the Hebrew name Shlomo ben Chaim or something like that then finds out his yichus is weird on mother's side and has a giyur l'chumrah, does his name change to Shlomo ben Avraham Avinu or is he still Shlomo ben Chaim?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may want to specify the circumstances in which you are calling upon the person (e.g. getting an 'aliyah, writing the kethuba, reading the kethuba, etc.), as there may be נפקא מינות.

Comment: I was more thinking about getting aliyah in my mind.

Comment: My guess is it varies by case.

Comment: IIRC there's no obligation to be called anything. One can pick up any name and any father's name. What matters (esp in ketubbah or Gett) is how the person is KNOWN in the community. My friend davens in a Chabadnic minyan and is called by the name of his gentile father.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to the case of a person who is adopted by a Jewish family and can call himself after the name of his adoptive father. [When an adopted child is called to the torah, how are they named?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36869/when-an-adopted-child-is-called-to-the-torah-how-are-they-named/36871#36871) has my answer to that question It might not be an exact duplicate because of the specific case given. In that answer, I state that I have known people who are known by the name of the adoptive father.

I also knew someone who was a *ger Lechumrah* who was called to the Torah using his father's name. Even if he was a ger, he could use his father's name in any case.